# make does not show option on pressing tab on centos

Tags: linux, centos, make, makefile

In my office i have ubuntu where in my project folder i have `Makefile`.

If i got to folder and then press make and then `tab` then it shows all option but at my home

i am pressing table after `Make` and instead of options it shows the files in the `dir`.

do i need to installing something

Comment: Have some pity upon the poor answerers!  For all that they know, you're using the Z Shell in your office with all sorts of fancy completion turned on and the Tenex C Shell at home with almost all completion turned off.  Give them information about what shell you're expecting this to work in.  They're not clairvoyant.

Comment: @JdeBP , i am using /bin/bash in both computers, i wonder in what cases that will be different because wherever i have worked , i have always seen /bin/bash

Answer (score 2):

You might need an additional `bash-completion` package, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188324/bash-completion-of-makefile-target

More relevant information can be found at http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/fedora-redhat-scientific-linuxenable-bash-completion/

> First, turn on the EPEL repo and type the following yum command to
>   install bash-completion package:

```
# yum install bash-completion
```

Comment: i tried that , tab is working but make file options are not showing which are inside the makefile

Comment: @user1721949 perhaps you have not set it up fully, have you followed the `source ...` step?